# Django server-side and client-side pagination with Datatables

Tags: django, datatables, django-views, django-filter

This might sound like a stupid question so apologies in case I'm wasting your time. I have a tons or results coming from my data in my Django project. It's a table with many columns and almost 4000 rows. I am using Datatables for pagination, filtering, horizontal scrolling, sorting the columns.

<s>Client-side</s> (I meant server-side)  I am also using django-filter for querying the database.

My problem is that the loading of the initial data (non filtered via django-filter) takes a lot of time. Shall I implement pagination on the <s>client-side</s> (I meant server-side)? If so, how does this work with Datatables? Will Datatables paginate/display only the (first page of) paginated data coming from the server-side query? Is there a way for the two to work together?

Thanks.

Comment: `django-filter` does not filter client-side, but server-side. The same with pagination: the actual pagination happens at the server side. You can use AJAX for example to load the next page, but the data should be paginated/filtered by the server, otherwise it does not make (much) difference in terms of performance.

Comment: You can load few records from one page of API and then when user scrolls down and reaches the end load the records from next page and so on.

Comment: Take a look at for example *infinite scroll* solutions with Django: https://dev.to/coderasha/infinite-scroll-with-django-d0a

Comment: Thank you @WillemVanOnsem, I'm still not sure what would happen to the Datatables table if I paginated server-side. The link about _infinite scroll_ with Django sounds promising, I'll give it a go later.

Comment: Also, I suspect that, the infinite scroll being client-side, it'll wait to receive all the data before applying it, like Datatables does, so there wouldn't be much change in performances as far as I can tell.

Comment: I just learned about this: https://pypi.org/project/django-serverside-datatable/#description which sounds like it's perfect for what I need to do. I'll try to implement it and see what happens.